# Why does OCaml only have first::rest on list, but not rest::last for list?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

In OCaml, for list, we always do `first::rest`. it is convenient to get the first element out of a list, or insert an element in front of a list.

But why does OCaml not have `rest::last`? Without `List`'s functions, we can't easily do getting last element of a list or insert an element to the end of a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The list datatype is not a magic builtin, only a regular recursive datatype with some syntactic sugar. You could implement it yourself, using `Nil` instead of `[]` and `Cons(first,rest)` instead of `first::rest`, in the following way:

```
type 'a mylist =
  | Nil
  | Cons of 'a * 'a mylist
```

I'm not sure if you will see the definition above as an answer to your question, but it really is: when you write `first::rest`, you're not calling a function, you're just using a datatype constructor that builds a new value (in constant time and space).

This definition is simple and has clear algorithmic properties: lists are immutable, accessing the first element of the list is `O(1)`, accessing the `k`-th element is `O(k)`, concatenation of two lists `li1` and `li2` is `O(length(li1))`, etc. In particular, accessing the last element or adding something at the end of a list `li` would be `O(length(li))`; we're not eager to expose this as a convenient operation because it is costly.

If you want to add elements at the end of a sequence, lists are not the right data structure. You may want to use a queue (if you follow a first-in, first-out access discipline), a `deque`, etc. There is a (mutable) `Queue` structure in the standard library, and the two third-party overlays [Core](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core/Dequeue.html) and [Batteries](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/blob/master/src/batDeque.mli) have a deque module (persistent in Batteries, mutable in Core).

Comment: +1 "we're not eager to expose this as a convenient operation because it is costly." says it all.

Answer (score 5):

Because lists are simply plain data types defined as

```
type 'a list = Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a list
```

except that you spell `Nil` as `[]` and `Cons` as infix `::`. In other words, lists are "singly-linked" if you want. There is no magic involved except for the syntax of the constructors. Obviously, to get to the last element, or append one, you need some auxiliary functions then.